# Parse includeKey works for an Array but not for a Pointer Object

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfquery, pfobject

I am currently working on an iOS app that connects to Parse and I am having difficulty in retrieving objects using the includeKey() function.

Lets say that I am adding a food item to my Food table:

```
var newFoodObject = PFObject(className: "Food")

//Here I am pointing to an existing object in my SubCategory table
newFoodObject["subCategory"] = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "SubCategory", objectId: "oisii1pZSP")
newFoodObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
   println(success)
   println(error)
}
```

Then lets say I want to retrieve that object:

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "Food")
query.includeKey("subCategory")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
  println(objects)
  println(error)
}
```

For some reason when I do this the SubCategory object is not included in the query coming back unless I save the SubCategory in an array in my Food table.

Any thoughts why the includeKey() functions works with an array of pointers but not with a single pointer?

Comment: Have you tried reading the contents of "subCategory" into a variable and printing that out? From what you've shown you are basing your conclusion on the results of `println(objects)` which I wouldn't expect to show the contents of "subCategory".

Comment: Hi Timothy. Thank you for your help. For some reason it works now. I might have removed a bug without knowing and solved this! Thank you anyways!